# Magento css windows 10

Tags: magento2, css

I´ve installed Magento on Windows 10, installed correctly but css doesn´t load, rewrite is configured on apache.

Comment: Have you try to deploy static files by command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i´m new to php, can you tell me how to do that

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html Your can see more here

Comment: Thank you, now i get this error: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73 bytes) in C:\www\magento\vendor\oyejorge\less.php\lib\Less\Visitor\processExtends.php on line 307"

Answer (score 7):

I hope this will help you

If you are using wamp server on windows localhost then

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\<Magento-root-directory>\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

in your CLI.

remove cache and try again.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this is useful for you

Goto Magento 2 root directory -> pub -> **static** and remove **static** folder and remove **var/cache, var/composer_home, var/generation, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed**

Then run,

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Thank, i´ve run the command, and throw this error: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in C:\www\magento\vendor\oyejorge\less.php\lib\Less\Tree\Selector.php on line 88"